react-audio-voice-recorder recording gets sent on cancel as well
I am using react-audio-voice-recorder library to implement voice recordings in a chatting app. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-voice-recorder
The library has this issue where if I use the useAudioRecorder hook, then the voice gets sent even when a user clicks discard. This is the issue:
https://github.com/samhirtarif/react-audio-recorder/issues/119
Is there any workaround for this? Anyway I can handle in onRecordingComplete to check if the user has clicked discard or save and work accordingly?
import { useChatContext } from "@/components/context/ChatContext";
import React from "react";
import { AudioRecorder } from "react-audio-voice-recorder";

const ChatVoiceRecorder = () => {
  const { onSendVoicemail } = useChatContext();
  const recorder = useAudioRecorder({
    noiseSuppression: true,
    echoCancellation: true,
  });

  return (
    <AudioRecorder
      onRecordingComplete={(blob) => {
        // Only send this if the voice is not discarded
        onSendVoicemail(blob);
      }}
      recorderControls={recorder}
      onNotAllowedOrFound={(err) => console.table(err)}
      classes={{
        AudioRecorderStatusClass: recorder.isPaused ? "paused" : undefined,
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ChatVoiceRecorder;

